# Status Listbox update problem using a Background Worker in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use a background worker to update a listbox used for a status window in my Form in C#. It doesn't appear to work properly when the addToStausLog() method is called from another class outside of the MyForm class even though I pass an instance of the form to the other class that's calling the addToStatusLog update member. Instead the update doesn't happen until the class member finished and returns back to the MyForm class. Maybe there's a better a approach to creating real-time status windows that will run from any class that MyForm is passed into. I'm new to worker threads, so could someone review and let me know what I might be doing wrong or could improve on.

```
        public MyForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Setup background task to update listbox status so UI is unaffected
            _lListBoxQue = new List<string>();
            bw_listBoxBGWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw_listBoxBGWorker.DoWork += (o, args) => LstbxThread_doWork();
            bw_listBoxBGWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, args) => LstbxThread_completed();
        }

        private void LstbxThread_doWork()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        private void LstbxThread_completed()
        {
            // Update listbox
            lstStatusBox.BeginUpdate();
            lstStatusBox.Items.Clear(); // clear entries
            lstStatusBox.Items.AddRange(_lListBoxQue.ToArray());
            lstStatusBox.EndUpdate();
        }

        public String addToStatusLog(String sMsg)
        {
            _lListBoxQue.Add(sMsg);
            if (_lListBoxQue.Count > _iStatusLogMaxLines)    // > max?
                _lListBoxQue.RemoveAt(0); // remove top element?

            if( !bw_listBoxBGWorker.IsBusy )    // background not busy?    
                bw_listBoxBGWorker.RunWorkerAsync();    // update listbox in back ground task           
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            return sMsg;
        }
```

This is the member that calls another class which attempts to call the addToStatusLog several times during the process, but the updates to the listbox don't happen until the MyClass(this).updateDB() finishes. I need to see real-time updates as the updateDB() function is running. There has to be a way to make this work, I'm hoping...

```
        private void btnUpdateDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (_bIsUpdateEventRunning == false ) // is event not busy?
        {
            _bIsUpdateEventRunning = true;
            new MyClass(this).updateDB();
            _bIsUpdateEventRunning = false;
        }

        }
```

Example of class called to update the form listbox.

```
    Public class MyClass{

            private MyForm _pForm;

            public MyClass(MyForm pForm){ _pForm= pForm; }

            public void updateDB(){ 
                _pForm.addToStatusLog("Hello World");
            }

    }
```

Updated Fix w/o background worker:

```
        public String addToStatusLog(String sMsg)
        {
            _lListBoxQue.Add(sMsg);
            if (_lListBoxQue.Count > _iStatusLogMaxLines)    // > max?
                _lListBoxQue.RemoveAt(0); // remove top element?

            lstStatusBox.BeginUpdate();
            lstStatusBox.Items.Clear(); // clear entries
            lstStatusBox.Items.AddRange(_lListBoxQue.ToArray());
            lstStatusBox.EndUpdate();
            Application.DoEvents();

            return sMsg;
        }
```

Comment: Why does your DoWork do no work?  Don't we need to see the updateDB() method you are calling if that's the code not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` is not the answer here. What you likely need is [`Application.DoEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents). This processes all messages currently waiting in the Windows message queue.

`Thread.Sleep` just tells the thread to go to sleep for the number of milliseconds you specify. If your background worker is running on the UI thread, you're putting the UI thread to sleep and it's effectively comatose. (**Important**: All Windows forms run on the UI thread.)

There are, of course, alternative designs that involve spinning up separate threads of execution. But these have their own issues, and you should be mindful of them before running blindly down that path.

Comment: Agree, I eliminated the background worker thread altogether for this task and added the Application.DoEvents after loading the listbox and that work perfectly. Tnx.